# Width tag not working html/css

Tags: html, css, image, width

I am doing this assignment for school and I need to side the background behind the slogans and little images so that it perfectly encloses the words. However, I can't get the width tag to work. Please help me find the source of this issue. Sorry for poor formatting. I am in a bit of a time crunch.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MNSportsInc</title>
</head>
<center><p><font size="8">Minnesota Sports Inc.</font></p></center>
<style>
    h1 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 300}
    h2 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 500}
    h3 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 500}
    h4 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 500}
        h5 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 500}
    h6 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 500}
</style>
<body>
<center>
    <h1><a href="https://www.mlb.com/twins"><img src="Twins.gif"></a>Twins 
get wins!<a href="https://www.mlb.com/twins"><img src="Twins.gif"></a></h1>
<!--Twins-->
    <h2><a href="https://www.nhl.com/wild"><img src="Wild.png"></a>Crack a 
smile for the Wild.<a href="https://www.nhl.com/wild"><img src="Wild.png">
</a></h2><!--Wild-->
    <h3><a href="http://www.vikings.com/"><img src="Vikings.png"></a>Buy 
things for the Vikings.<a href="http://www.vikings.com/"><img 
src="Vikings.png"></a></h3><!--Vikings-->
    <h4><a href="http://www.nba.com/timberwolves/"><img src="Wolves.jpg">
</a>Fans pull the Wolves!<a href="http://www.nba.com/timberwolves/"><img 
src="Wolves.jpg"></a></h4><!--Timberwolves-->
    <h5><a href="http://www.gophersports.com/"><img src="UofM.png"></a>Beat 
the Gophers? No sir!<a href="http://www.gophersports.com/"><img 
src="UofM.png"></a></h5><!--UofM-->
    <h6><a href="http://crimson-activities.com/"><img src="Crimson.jpg">
</a>The Crimson have Risen.<a href="http://crimson-activities.com/"><img 
src="Crimson.jpg"></a></h6><!--Crimson-->
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just looks like you'll need to provide the unit of measurement you'd like to use like px, em, pt, %, in, cm, mm, etc.

Comment: Be aware that your school is teaching you HTML from 20 years ago...

Comment: you are trying to apply width on <h> tag... <h> tag has no width attribute.. please read https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: increase font size of <h> tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your settings for the `width` property (not tag) lack a unit, so those settings are ignored according to CSS specs. They work if you append e.g. the `px` unit (for CSS pixel) to them: `width: 500px`. Pixels are what you probably meant to use. It’s a completely different question how to set the background so that it “perfectly encloses the words”; you probably need a different approach, like using inline elements (which take just as much width as needed).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MNSportsInc</title>
</head>
<center><p><font size="8">Minnesota Sports Inc.</font></p></center>
<style>
    h1 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 300px}
    h2 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 500px}
    h3 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 500px}
    h4 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 500px}
        h5 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 500px}
    h6 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 500px}
</style>
<body>
<center>
    <h1><a href="https://www.mlb.com/twins"><img src="Twins.gif"></a>Twins 
get wins!<a href="https://www.mlb.com/twins"><img src="Twins.gif"></a></h1>
<!--Twins-->
    <h2><a href="https://www.nhl.com/wild"><img src="Wild.png"></a>Crack a 
smile for the Wild.<a href="https://www.nhl.com/wild"><img src="Wild.png">
</a></h2><!--Wild-->
    <h3><a href="http://www.vikings.com/"><img src="Vikings.png"></a>Buy 
things for the Vikings.<a href="http://www.vikings.com/"><img 
src="Vikings.png"></a></h3><!--Vikings-->
    <h4><a href="http://www.nba.com/timberwolves/"><img src="Wolves.jpg">
</a>Fans pull the Wolves!<a href="http://www.nba.com/timberwolves/"><img 
src="Wolves.jpg"></a></h4><!--Timberwolves-->
    <h5><a href="http://www.gophersports.com/"><img src="UofM.png"></a>Beat 
the Gophers? No sir!<a href="http://www.gophersports.com/"><img 
src="UofM.png"></a></h5><!--UofM-->
    <h6><a href="http://crimson-activities.com/"><img src="Crimson.jpg">
</a>The Crimson have Risen.<a href="http://crimson-activities.com/"><img 
src="Crimson.jpg"></a></h6><!--Crimson-->
</center>
</body>
</html>
htmlcssimagewidth
```

Answer (score 0):

Header tags, like `h1` are block level elements, so the "try" to stretch over the width of parent or window.

You can change its `display` style to block to change this:

```
h1 {color: white; background: black; font-family: times; font-size: 
120%; width: 300px;display:inline-block}
```

See the fiddle I"ve made here: https://jsfiddle.net/v3f13vtb/

Answer (score 0):

You should put your CSS stylings in a different file and then link to it, I think the reason your styling isn't working inline is because of the fact that you aren't telling it what to do. 500(of what) 500px? 500%? Try writing it more semantically and see what happens.